# postfix - where is located pid/inet.smtp

Tags: postfix

When I restart postfix I receive the error:

**"fatal: open lock file pid/inet.smtp: cannot create file exclusively: No such file or directory"**

in the logs.

Where is located that file?

My server is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: How did you install `postfix`?

Comment: It is generally a good idea to quote the command line used in your question. I suspect you did not attempt restart through the intended (by your distributor) method.

Answer (score 0):

Since most postfix daemons are **chrooted**, it is usually located somewhere inside *"/var/spool/postfix"*.

Try */var/spool/postfix/pid/*